# Compare files in directory structure between two servers in Linux

Tags: linux, centos7

I have two Centos 7 boxes where there is an identical folder structure on each. The files between them are meant to be same.

However because of replication issues I want to check to see what files are missing from Server B that exists Server A between two dates. If any files are missing to make a copy to another folder on Server A where they then be copied into Server B in one go

Comment: "that exists Server A between two dates".  You can only find files that still exist now, not files that existed between two dates.

Comment: Can't you use the timestamp of when they were written

Comment: If the file still exists, yes.  But not for files that have been removed since the second date.

Comment: I think I can live with that because replication only happens once a week. So is there a way I could do this

Comment: check my answer

Answer (score 0):

Run this command to find the files modified (eg. written to) between 10 and 5 days ago, eg. on server A

```
cd /identic/directory/
find . -type f -mtime -10 -mtime +5  > /tmp/files_A.txt
```

Do the same on server B, except for the filename, obvious, /tmp/files_B.txt

Copy one of the files to the other system's /tmp folder and run

```
cd /tmp
diff files_[AB].txt  | less -X
```

This will give you missing files.

If you want to check file sizes and modification times, add the "-ls" option to find:

```
find . -type f -mtime -10 -mtime +5  -ls > /tmp/files_A.txt
```

You may need to play with the number of days, they are counted from the current time(!), not day.